# Does watch() in Vue 3 behave differently in development vs production?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuex

Just wondering if I've missed something or don't quite understand it, but I have this block of code that runs fine on development locally, but wont run on production.

```
 watch: {
        $route(to, from) {
           console.log('called within watch');
           //code below here calls a vuex mutation
         }
    }
```

I don't get the console log printed at all on production. The console.logs are not hidden because they work otherwise if I print one in the created method example. And the mutation thats in the $route also doesn't run on production, but does locally.

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. There's no reason to assume it's watch, while you have a problem with the router specifically

Comment: Also in addition to what @Estus asked, can you watch the route deeply? See here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers